# Change bundle content per user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I am using Bundles with CDN in my ASP MVC web application.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/HomeJs", Util.BuildCDNURL("../../bundles/HomeJs"))
                .Include("~/Scripts/HomePage.js"));
```

As I understand, the bundles are registered in the App_Start(), where I am calling it.

However, I would like to add some extra logic to my Util.BuildCDNURL() method based on the current user request. In my app, I have a "Use CDN" value for each user login.

Can I manipulate my CDN path based on this value, different for every user?

Comment: Why don't you just dynamically change the script thats loaded in the via or view a child action?

Comment: Moved the BuildCDNURL() method as below and got what i needed -

 @Scripts.Render(Util.BuildCDNURL(Url.Content("~/bundles/HomeJs")))

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to change the directory from where to take the css files.
You could use the same thing with your CDN path to build the bundles.

```
public static class DynamicBundles
{
    public static IHtmlString RenderSkin(string skinDirectory)
    {            
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/" + skinDirectory).Include(
        "~/Content/" + skinDirectory + "/reset.css", 
        "~/Content/" + skinDirectory + "/site.css", 
        "~/Content/" + skinDirectory + "/grids.css"));

    return Styles.Render("~/Content/css/" + skinDirectory);
    }
}
```

Then use it inside the view like so:

```
@DynamicBundles.RenderSkin(skinDirectory)
```